# ASP.NET Web Forms Method With JQuery Ajax Request Failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to call code behind method from client side ajax request. It returns success but it never goes inside this method. Here is my code:

Code Behind:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static void Test()
        {
            var ceva = "I was called";
        }
```

javascript ajax request:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Default.aspx/Test",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error : function(data , data2 , data3) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            });
```

Comment: How do you verify it never executes the method? Did you put a Debug.Print statement in there...?

Comment: Yes I put but it never goes there.

Comment: Try to add data property to ajax (could be an empty value, like `data: {}`) and add `dataType: "json"`

Comment: Again nothing happened.

Comment: You checked with firebug or the developer toolbar, in the net section, the call? maybe the content type or something else is wrong in the call

Comment: Try to change `url` as following: `'<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Default.aspx/Test") %>;` Also, show how this code invoked on client

Comment: When I checked the call it says: POST Test 200 OK. When I put break point there nothing. I tried to place wrong name method /Default.aspx/Testttttt and it said again 200 OK. Very strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try: (tested and working)

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Test",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error : function(data) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
```

code:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string Test()
{
        return "I was called";
}
```